# Is there a screen reader app that can read out webpages?

Tags: screen, speech

Does the Windows phone store have an app that can read out webpages, ebooks or text like the Microsoft reader or [Balabolka reader](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Science-CAD/Balabolka.shtml) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Surfy browser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/surfy-browser/9wzdncrfhvrf) is an excellent app that can read your webpages aloud.

[Poki](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/poki-for-pocket/9wzdncrdrd3l) can read you articles stored in Pocket.